# Azure Cosmos DB - How 20 GB data stored in one collection with no Partition key?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

As we know there is a 10 GB size limit of each logical partition key in the collection. I haven't created any partition key for my collection but i can see 20GB data stored in that collection.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently Microsoft announced for Azure Cosmos DB it has increased the size of logical partitions for customers to 20 GB, doubling the size from 10 GB. Announcement was done in March 2020 please find the below link

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/cosmos-db-partition-size-20gb/